# Problem when i used some large large value i get wrong output with my function

Tags: c++, function, combinations, binomial-coefficients

So I'm new to stackoverflow and coding I was learning about functions in c++ and how the stack frame works etc..
in that I made a function for factorials and used that to calculate binomial coefficients. it worked fine for small values like n=10 and r=5 etc... but for large a medium value like 23C12 it gave 4 as answer.

IDK what is wrong with the code or I forgot to add something.

My code:

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact(int n)
{
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a *= i;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int n, r;
    cin >> n >> r;
    if (n >= r)
    {
        int coeff = fact(n) / (fact(n - r) * fact(r));
        cout << coeff << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "please enter valid values. i.e n>=r." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 23C12 ? Whats that "C" ?

Comment: `23!` is `25852016738884976640000`, that's a little bit more than the maximum value for an `int`.

Comment: oh that C represents combination or binomial coefficients here 23C12 will mean 23!/((23-12)!*12!

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything "wrong" per se. It's just that factorials quicky become huge numbers.

In your example you're using `int`s, which are typically 32-bit variables. If you take a look at a table of factorials, you'll note that `log2(13!) = 32.535...`. So the largest factorial that will fit in a 32-bit number is `12!`. For a 64-bit variable, the largest factorial you can store is `20!` (since `log2(21!) = 65.469...`).

When you get `4` as the result that's because of overflow.

If you need to be able to calculate such huge numbers, I suggest a bignum library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: yeah i just realized that i tried using long int still faced same problem. thanks for you help!

Comment: @AbhayKumar Note that `long int` is equivalent to `int` (i.e. both are 32-bit) on Windows platforms. On linux `long int` is 64-bit. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types. I suggest using `int64_t` if you need 64-bit variables (bonus: it explicitly shows you that 64-bit variables will be used, no need to think about which platform the code will be compiled on).

Comment: ooh okay, I will start using `int64_t` more I didn't know about it till now. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhayKumar Don't forget to `#include <cstdint>` to have `int64_t` (and friends) defined.

Comment: ahh ok, are there no other data type for storing large numbers in any standard library of c++?

Comment: There's some non-standardized types, such as `__int128` in GCC. However, for longer (and arbitrary) lengths, you best bet would be a bignum library like GMP, which I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Factorials overflow easily. In practice you rarely need bare factorials, but they almost always appear in fractions. In your case:

```
int coeff = fact(n) / (fact(n - r) * fact(r));
```

Note the the first `min(n,n-r,r)` factors of the denominator and numerator are identical. I am not going to provide you the code, but I hope an example will help to understand what to do instead.

Consider `n=5`, `r=3` then `coeff` is

```
  5*4*3*2*1 / 2*1 * 3*2*1
```

And before actually carrying out any calculations you can reduce that to

```
  5*4 / 2*1
```

If you are certain that the final result `coeff` does fit in an `int`, you can also calculate it using `int`s. You just need to take care not to overflow the intermediate terms.